# Creating a Vertical "drop" down menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

The title probably doesn't actually describe the issue properly. I want to create a menu for my website that is a vertical menu on the left side, and when you hover over an option with sub-options those sub-options pop out to the side (doesn't really matter at the moment). The issue I'm having is that when they pop out they push down all the other options, and I get this navigation bar that doesn't look good at all. If someone could help me fix this so I don't shove everything else out of the way even though they aren't overlapping, that would be appreciated.

The HTML I use.

```
<ul id="nav">

<li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Imaging</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

The CSS I use.

```
ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

a {
display:block;
width:60px;
}

#nav ul {
    display: none;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

that is because your document is having all the elements in a line and will always show them one after the other!

So my advice for you would be to just use

```
position: absolute;
```

This way you can align the elements over the document without interefering the current document style and element alignment!

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

I would position the ul inside your li absolute.

```
position:absolute;
```

When you do this the element will hover above the li-parent. When you try a little with positive and negative margin you will be able to put the hover element next to it parent.
It will be something like this:

```
#nav li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
float: left;
margin-left:60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it did the trick! Now I just need to apply it to the main thing I'm working on.